# Drupal Multi Site Single Authentication System

Tags: authentication, drupal-8, json-api

I am trying to build a single authentication system between several drupal sites in our organization.
The requirement is that users in drupal site A can perform certain actions in drupal site B.

I have a wrapper API on site A that calls Drupal JSON API (user needs to be authenticated) that the users on site B can call to perform the actions.

Here is what I am thinking to do:
1. Create separate identity system.
2. Create a shadow user account in each drupal system.
3. User logs into the identity system and gets authentication ticket.

Since we use JSON API for CRUD operations, I am stuck at the point at how the JSON API on site A will authenticate with the token passed in the request header as the user was authenticated in a separate system.
[image]